# Entity Framwork Using composite key object null reference exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, key, nullreferenceexception, composite

I need to have a reference table to combine these two entities. I have built the following table, and unfortunately it is not working. Is there an easier way of doing this? Or can someone please explain why the entity will keeps throwing a null reference error, when I try and create it in the controller?

```js
public class BridgeTable
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Entity1ID { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public string Entity2ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Entity1 entity1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Entity2 entity2 { get; set; }

    }

public class Entity1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        …

        public virtual List<BridgeTable> bridgeTable { get; set; }
    }

public class Entity2
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        …

        public virtual BridgeTable bridgeTable { get; set; }
    }
```

My model builder:

```js
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<BridgeTable>().HasRequired<Entity2>(e => e.bridgeTable).WithRequiredDependent();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Throws this exception:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

In my controller post method:

BridgeTable bridgeTable = new BridgeTable {

```js
        public DbSet<Entity1> entity1{ get; set; }

        public DbSet<BridgeTable> bridgeTable { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Entity2> entity2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you need additional fields in your bridge table? Or you just want implement many to many relation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it? (also known as Object reference not set to an instance of an object)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it-also-known-as-object-refe)

Comment: I figured out what was happening, one of the things I was setting was an object. I neglected to put a hiddenfor in the view to pass it along its id so it was causing null. I posted this, because I couldn't figure out why it was saying that the object itself was a null reference, I thought it may have had to do with something related to how I was creating the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is just a rather obtuse way of saying you attempted to reference a property off of a variable that resolved to null at runtime. Consider the following:

```
Foo foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
```

In the above, `foo` is supposed to be an instance of `Foo`, which *does* have a property `Bar` (for the sake of example), so the code compiles fine. However, once the code actually runs, if no `Foo`s were found in your table with the particular id, `foo` is set to `null`, which does *not* have a property `Bar`. As a result, you get the "Object reference blah blah" error message.

If the error is triggering on the line where you have `BridgeTable bridgeTable = new BridgeTable {`, most likely, you're initializing one of the properties with a variable evaluating to `null` that you're reference a property or method on. For example:

```
BridgeTable bridgeTable = new BridgeTable {
    Entity1ID = entity1.ID
    ...
};
```

And, `entity1` is actually `null`. Run the code in debug mode and inspect all the variables you're trying to initialize with. Fix the null, or coalesce the null somehow (`entity1 == null ? 0 : entity1.ID`), and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out what was happening, one of the things I was setting was an object. I neglected to put a hiddenfor in the view to pass along its id so it was causing null.